# Could not load file or assembly for AppDomain in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I load an assembly into an appdomain via:

```
            var appdomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
            //string appBase = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            //string appBase = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
            appdomainSetup.ApplicationBase = _appBase;//System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath: Injected into cstor
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase);
            appdomainSetup.DisallowBindingRedirects = false;
            appdomainSetup.DisallowCodeDownload = true;
            appdomainSetup.ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;

            appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("myAppdomain", null, appdomainSetup);
```

where `BLASSEMBLYLOCATION = "c:\path\myAssembly.dll";//for now just hard coded path`

Then I grab a type from this assembly in another method:

```
var helperObject= appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("myssembly.NameContinued", "myNamespace.BL.Helper") as Helper;//ERROR LINE HERE
```

This all works just fine and dandy in a unit test.  However, this blows up with error when run through the web application:

> Could not load file or assembly 'myssembly.NameContinued' or one of
>   its dependencies.

I can reproduce the `FileNotFoundException` in my unit test by not specifying

`appdomainSetup.ApplicationBase`

I suspect the issue has to do with the directory I set as ApplicationBase.  In the web program I pass the value of `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath` which I see to be `"/"`.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I set the ApplicationPath equal to the path where I put my assembly:

```
appdomainSetup.ApplicationPath = @"c:\path";
```

Because this assembly is referenced by the web project, I expected my assembly to be included in the same directory as my web project so I could use relative paths (much like `bin` folders work).  However, for whatever reason this just isn't working.  Specifying the full path as it lives on the server is thus far the only solution that worked.